# Casimir Effect and parallel $D$-Branes

Tags: string-theory, branes, casimir-effect

In the well-known setup for the calculation of the Casimir effect, we take 2 perfectly reflecting plates, impose the appropriate boundary conditions on the relevant fields (scalar, vector, etc.) and calculate the energy of this configuration.

So the most natural analog of plates (that is objects that impose boundary conditions on fields) in String Theory are $D$-Branes. This got me wondering whether a similar scenario can be realized in String Theory where we consider the energy of an open or closed string field theory interacting with 2 parallel $D$-Branes.

The scenario I had in mind is loosely related to figure1. in [Scattering of Strings from $D$-branes](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9611214). I know that $D$-branes have open strings stretched between them, but that scenario would not be analogous to the Casimir effect setting because there is no **propagation**.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why string field theory?

Comment: @NiharKarve Isn't string field theory the natural habitat for such a question?

Comment: I mean, string theory has D-branes and spacetime fields as well. Restricting to string field theory unnecessarily reduces the potential answerer pool for this question by a huge amount.

Comment: @NiharKarve OK, now I understand your point. Excuse my ignorance, but how does introducing another tag reduce the answerer pool? Shouldn't it increase the number, if the tag is related that is.

Comment: The string field theory formalism of string theory is a lot more difficult and much less well-known than the "standard" formulation of string theory that is presented first. Remember that "string field theory" $\ne$ "fields in string theory" (which is what I assume you were going for there)

Comment: @NiharKarve Nope I wasn't going for that.

Comment: @NiharKarve I was imagining a scenario like https://cds.cern.ch/record/315619/files/9611214.pdf. Closed strings scattering of D-branes.

Comment: That's my point though - there's nothing here that's specific to the string field theory formalism. By the way, you might find https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.2898 interesting.

Comment: @NiharKarve Apologies for my mixing of the 2 subjects. Thanks for your suggestion, I will have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, there is no analogue of Casimir effect in between two parallel D-branes. The reason in supersymmetry.**

Two D-branes interact with each other by means of open strings stretched among them. The one-loop amplitude for open strings streched between two D-branes is exactly computable (see equation (48) in [TASI Lectures on D-Branes](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9611050)) and shown to be exactly zero.

This shouldn't be so surprising, since parallel D-branes break only
half of supersymmetry, therefore the "no-force condition" between two BPS states is satisfied.

Comment: OK $D$-branes have open strings stretched between them, but what about string interacting with $D$-branes. Consider a scenario where a closed string is scatterred of from a $D$-brane.

Comment: @hep-py That scenario is exactly equivalent to the one I described ( see [open-closed string duality](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/open%2Fclosed+string+duality)).Also notice that you can't possibly circumvent the argument because is based on supersymmetry. It doesn't matter how do you prove the system of parallel D-branes. The invariant fact is that both preserve half of the supersymmetries and as a consequence there is a no-force condition between them.

Comment: I see. I have to read that reference you have provided. But another question: what if we just consider bosonic string theory, therefore there would be no discussion regarding supersymmetry, and therefore there may be a non vanishing contribution.

Comment: @hep-py In bosonic string theory the two D-branes experience an attractive force and annihilate as a result of tachyon condensation. That's the basic mechanism behind brane hybrid inflation see the excellent book "D-Brane: Superstrings and New Perspective of Our World" (the part of applications of D-branes to cosmology).

Comment: Interesting. But what keeps D-branes from anhilating in superstring theory?

Comment: @hep-py Good question, the answer is, again, supersymmetry. Bosonic string theory has tachyons, in particular, open strings stretched between two parallel branes have a mass spectrum that depends on the brane separation (see the first chapther on D-branes in "A first course in string theory" ) and if that separation goes below a value (the string scale) the branes develop tachyon modes (this is worked in detail in Zwiebach's textbook).

Comment: @hep-py In superstring theory there are no tachyons because of the [GSO projection](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/159510/what-is-the-motivation-behind-the-gso-projection-in-superstring-theory) .[This paper](http://edu.itp.phys.ethz.ch/fs13/cft/SuperS2_Majer.pdf) is an excellent introduction to this important construction.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the answers. I got one more question. I am currently working my way through Zweibach's and its been wonderful. I am currently in chapter 9, coming near bosonic string quantization. What books and articles would you recommend for supplementing Zweibach and developing some familiarity with advanced concepts?

Comment: @hep-py Sometimes Zweibach's texbook seems slow, but believe me, If you dominate the material in the book you would immediately develop strong intuition about the subject as a whole. So, stay motivated! Concerning the references. The answer strongly depends of what are your aspirations; phenomenology, black holes, holography, the subject in itself etc. But as a general recommendation is to try to have the books "Introduction to Conformal Field Theory: With Applications to String Theory" and "Basic Concepts of String Theory" in mind.

Comment: @hep-py They give you enough knowledge to understand papers and understand the incredibly beauty of the subject.  I also recommend the paper [Introduction to M-theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9811019) to be aware of the mystery of the beautiful structure of the theory.

Comment: It's true that Zweibach seems slow at times, but it's a really great book with all those amazing problems at the end of each chapter. I am mostly interested in black holes, holography and matrix models. Would you happen to know references for those specific subjects?

Comment: @hep-py Personally, I work on matrix models and I can't recommend nothing better than [Review of Matrix Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9712072). The standard reference [TASI Lectures on Matrix Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9911068) is not pedagogical at all, but it's a great roadmap to the literature.

Comment: @hep-py For a conceptual understanding of how string theory achieves a successful microscopic description of the black hole thermodynamics see [Conceptual Analysis of Black Hole Entropy in String Theory
](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.03232), [Emergence and Correspondence for String Theory Black Holes
](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.03234) and [TASI lectures on the Holographic Principle
](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0002044). Technical reviews are [The quantum structure of black holes](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0510180)

Comment: @hep-py ... and and [Black Holes in String Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9607235#:~:text=We%20consider%20black%20holes%20in,five%20and%20four%20spacetime%20dimensions.). For excellent reviews of the recent developments on the information paradox at the undergraduate level see [Lessons from the Information Paradox](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.05770) and [The entropy of Hawking radiation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.06872#:~:text=We%20show%20how%20the%20method,with%20unitary%20black%20hole%20evaporation.).